# $\lambda_2$ of Laplacian of a regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

Given a $d$-regular graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V| =n$. We know that the smallest eigenvalue of the normalized laplacian matrix of $G$ is $0$. I have seen the formulation of the second smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ in terms of the rayleigh quotient. However, the below paper mentions it in a way which I am not aware of.

How to derive the below (or similar) formulation of $\lambda_2$? Or am I horribly wrong in my interpretation?

$\lambda_2 = \min\limits_{\overline{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n, ||\overline{v}||=1} \dfrac{\mathbb{E}_{(u,v) \in E} ||\overline{u}-\overline{v}||^2}{\mathbb{E}_{u,v \in V} ||\overline{u}-\overline{v}||^2}$

**Source** : Proof of Theorem 7.1 (Section 7) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2234.pdf

Comment: Can you explain the notation? What do the $\Bbb E$ stand for and what is the $\bar u$?

Comment: For each vertex $u \in V$, $\overline{u}$ is a vector of unit length in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: And $\mathbb{E}$ denotes the expectation. For eg, the numerator can be written of as,  $\sum_{(u, v) \in E} 1/|E| \cdot ||\overline{u}-\overline{v}||^2$ and the denomiator as, $\sum_{u, v \in V} 1/|V|^2 \cdot ||\overline{u}-\overline{v}||^2$.

Comment: Then there is still something off. You cannot use $\bar v$ as a bound variable in the $\min$ and the sum (in the expectation value) at the same time. Also, which vector is $\bar u$ exactly? This seems not well defined to me.

Comment: I just checked the paper, and the formula there is different from what you wrote. First, the minimum is over all assignments of unit vectors to vertices (if I understand $\bar u$ as you explained). Second, the expectation value in the denominator is not over $V$ but over some other set $\mathcal P_1$ from some "bisection", whatever that means.

Comment: They are calling the graph $G_1 = (P_1, E_1)$ as a regular expander which I have relabelled to $G = (V,E)$. The choice for vectors in $V \setminus P_1$ does not matter in the minimization.